# Google Optimize Experiment sessions not divided equall

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing, google-optimize

During my two recent Google Optimize 'Redirect' experiments that I have run, traffic has not been divided equally over the variants within my experiment.

I have set the weight of each page equally (50% and 50%), which I read should take care of traffic being split equally as well.

I understand traffic won't ever be split perfectly equal. But In my results, almost all traffic seems to go to the losing Variant. I'm talking like 10k sessions to one Variant and just 1k to the other in experiments that ran at least two weeks.

Can anyone explain why this happens? Am I setting up something wrong, or is this supposed to happen?

Here's a screenshot of the results of one of the experiments in Google Optimize:

[image]